# How to place several divs next to another inside of a container without affecting the container or the children dimensions

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I need to place several divs inside a container div. The main issue is the with of the container is 100% to fit the available space and the inner divs can overflow it.

The inner divs do have a fixed width and height.

The main requirement is the container div displays an horiz scrollbar if overflow.

I have this:

```
<div style={{ width: "70%", background: "azure" }}>
    <div
      style={{
        width: "100%",
        overflowX: "auto",
        display: "flex",
        border: "solid 1px #c1c1c1",
        padding: "5px"
      }}
    >
      {Array.from({ length: 10 }, (_, index) => (
        <div
          key={index}
          style={{
            width: "120px",
            height: "200px",
            border: "solid 1px",
            backgroundColor: "lightblue",
            marginRight: "5px"
          }}
        >
          Item {index + 1}
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  </div>
```

But instead of displaying the horizontal scrollbar it insists in resize divs. [Here is the corresponding sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/inspiring-mcnulty-6y5n94?file=/src/App.js:132-819).

How can I solve this? What am I missing here?

Comment: It looks fine in Firefox, together with a horizontal scroll bar.

Comment: Thanks for the notice! Will try it in Firefox as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `flex-shrink` CSS property to `0` so that the inner `<div>` elements do not shrink.

```
<div
  key={index}
  style={{
    width: "120px",
    height: "200px",
    border: "solid 1px",
    backgroundColor: "lightblue",
    marginRight: "5px",
    flexShrink: 0
  }}
>
  Item {index + 1}
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

add flexShrink: 0 style to the child elements
the flex property is making the child to shrink as the shrink is set to 1 as default =, So make it 0

```
<div style={{ width: "70%", background: "azure" }}>
    <div
      style={{
        width: "100%",
        overflowX: "auto",
        display: "flex",
        border: "solid 1px #c1c1c1",
        padding: "5px"
      }}
    >
      {Array.from({ length: 10 }, (_, index) => (
        <div
          key={index}
          style={{
            flexShrink: "0",// here
            width: "120px",
            height: "200px",
            border: "solid 1px",
            backgroundColor: "lightblue",
            marginRight: "5px"
          }}
        >
          Item {index + 1}
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  </div>
```